# Start playing on mouse over event (without using Action Script)

Tags: javascript, flash-cs5, flash

I have created a php page with a SWF flash file is imported with a classic tag `<object>`, with Autoplay set to false.

When the mouse hovers over the flash component, I would like this to start playing. I'm not interesting in "mouse out behavior". (It should continue playing even if the pointer is moved away.)

I have seen Action Script perform this behavior, but there are no project files with flash movies. So I cannot open it in project mode; I only can "see" it in "read mode".

How can I set this behavior without using Action Script inside my flash project?

I can manage the mouse events with a simple javascript code: I can open an alert message (thanks to [onMouseover a flash element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630830/onmouseover-a-flash-element)) but I cannot pass the play command to the flash object.

Here is what I have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("id-of-my-movie").onmouseover = over;
function over(evt)
{
    document.getElementById("id-of-my-movie").play();
} 
</script>   

using .play() both PlayMovie()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no way to do this without **any** code inside Flash. If you've said that it won't autoplay, then only AS3 code can make it play.

You can use Javascript to call Flash functions, but the flash movie **must** have at least a few lines in order to receive those callbacks. You can check how to do this here: [AS3 function call from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17065766/as3-function-call-from-javascript)